# Why injecting a php tag with XSS dosn't work?

Tags: php, xss, injection

So you all know about the XSS vulnerability but what I cannot understand is
 how come injecting a `<?php ?>` tag doesn't work? eg.:
suppose there is a Stored XSS vulnerability in the index.php of a site why it doesn't work if you did this:
1. close the php tag `?>` 
2.open a new one `<?php` 
3.inject your php code and close it again

Comment: XSS = interpreted on client side. Clients don't deal/understand PHP. To inject dynamic PHP would be possible in very very very specific contexts and XSS are completely unrelated to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `index.php` file is already being processed.  When you attempt to inject a `?>` tag into the file, you're actually injecting it into the page that will eventually be sent to the client.